# Установка NET Core SDK 6.0 в Docker-контейнер: они что, издеваются?

Tags: .net, ubuntu, docker, .net-core

я прошу прощения за несколько эпатирующий заголовок вопроса.

Вопрос вызван вот чем: я потратил уже довольно много времени, пытаясь установить `dotnet sdk` внутрь докеровских образов.

В принципе, весь процесс "закодирован" вот в таком Dockerfile:

```
    FROM ubuntu:latest
    RUN apt-get update
    RUN apt-get install -y wget
    RUN wget https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/22.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb -O packages-microsoft-prod.deb
    RUN dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb
    RUN rm packages-microsoft-prod.deb
    RUN apt-get update
    RUN apt-get install -y apt-transport-https
    ENV DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT=1
    RUN apt-get install -y dotnet-sdk-6.0
    # dotnet sdk is installed!

    STOPSIGNAL SIGQUIT
```

Этот докерфайл я запускаю командами

```
    docker build -t make_synchro_bot-image -f Dockerfile .

    docker run -it --name make_synchro_bot-cont -d make_synchro_bot-image
```

Потом я коннекчусь внутрь контейнера,

```
    docker exec -it make_synchro_bot-cont /bin/bash
```

и у меня команда

`dotnet --version` говорит...

```
The command could not be loaded, possibly because:
  * You intended to execute a .NET application:
      The application '--version' does not exist.
  * You intended to execute a .NET SDK command:
      No .NET SDKs were found.

Download a .NET SDK:
https://aka.ms/dotnet-download

Learn about SDK resolution:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/sdk-not-found
```

При этом `dotnet`, `dotnet --info` - работают, а команда `dotnet --list-sdks` показывает пустой список установленных SDK

(см. приложенную картинку)

И вот у меня вопрос: **что бы это, черт побери, значило?**

я всё делаю по [руководству](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu)

Причем, эта проблема проявляется на конкретном сервере, и, как назло, на продакшене.

Версию докера - обновил до последней, кеши, как мог, почистил, лишние имиджи удалил, `docker images prune` - сделал, пересобрал... результат - тот же самый!

В принципе, я готов бросить это джело и воспользоваться готовыми докер-образами. Просто я не особо понимаю пока, с какими трудностями я столкнусь. Мне нужно внутри контейнера выполнить команду

```
    dotnet publish
```

Если Вы дадите мне рекомендации, как делать "то же самое, но по-другому" - я буду благодарен

P.S. Последние вести с полей: наткнулся на [такой вот репозиторий](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/main/documentation/scenarios/installing-dotnet.md), сижу, изучаю... пытаюсь понять, где я не прав.

[image: dotnet SDK не работает]

Comment: вопрос немного не по теме, а почему вы не используете готовые образы?

Comment: `--version` - "Выводит версию пакета SDK .NET, используемого командамиdotnet, которые могут повлиять на файл global.json. Доступен только при установке пакета SDK." [дока](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet). Вы же ставите `dotnet-runtime-6.0`, который не SDK

Comment: @ExplodingKitten - к сожалению, я не знаю, что находится в готовых образах. к тому же, этих готовых образов, мягко говоря, больше одного. Когда я сам делаю образ - я понимаю, что я там накрутил. Но если Вы считаете, что смысла рразбиратьсянет совсем - не могли бы Вы написать ответ в духе "перестань заниматься ерундой, вот единственно верная ссылка на готовый образ, вот так допиши сюда одну строчку для запуска твоего приложения" - такой ответ я приму с благодарностью.

Comment: @vitidev - я пробовал ставить и SDK, и runtime - всегда одно и то же. Черт бы с ней, с версией, мне важно, что потом не работает команда dotnet publish

Comment: из вопроса не следует что вы ставите sdk и ни слова про publish. Переделывайте вопрос под то как вы ставите SDK и какой ответ дает publish. А с `dotnet --version` версией все понятно

Comment: Может у вас какие-то переменные окружения нужно установить. Пробовали через [скрипт](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/core/install/linux-scripted-manual#scripted-install)?

Comment: @TigerTV.ru - спасибо за подсказку, как раз это было следующим в моём списке "что еще можно попробовать". Просто я не понимаю, почему в одном случае этого докервфайла достаточно, а в другом - нет! просто два разных сервера. одна архитектура, один линукс, одно ВСЁ.

Comment: @vitidev - Ваши замечания совершенно справедливы, откорректировал вопрос!

Comment: Используйте готовые образы с установленным SDK, зачем изобретать то что уже есть и хорошо работает)
но если очень хочется вот к примеру на debian (а выше уровнем и другие докер файлы есть):
https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/main/src/sdk/6.0/bullseye-slim/amd64/Dockerfile

Comment: По поводу "готовых образов больше одного" - это отсылка к порносборкам винды? Ну тут есть контраргумент в виде ссылки на https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/architecture/microservices/net-core-net-framework-containers/official-net-docker-images . А по поводу "я не знаю, что находится в готовых образах" - ну если мы говорим про **официальные** образы от майков - то тут тоже контрвопрос: а что хранится внутри `/usr/bin/dotnet`? Ну и про https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/main/src/sdk/6.0/focal/amd64/Dockerfile не забываем.

Comment: @donRumata Уважаемые Vein и don Rumata - спасибо за Ваши комментарии и ссылки в них. Попробую перейти на готовое! (термин "порносборка винды" мне встретился вперывые и... порадовал :-) )

Comment: Да ладно. Вроде устоявшееся выражение на уровне "сборка от Васяна". Собсно под "порно" понимается обычно несколько вещей: 1. Ты будешь "долбиться" с ней больше, потому что условный Васян закостомайзил то, чего не следует. 2. Характерный признак - часто обои с полуголыми женщинами, ну потому что это по-взрослому. 3. Из-за "честности" - обычно туда сразу встроены баннеры, которые закрывают пол экрана и рассказывают тебе, что ты смотрел порно, а если не переведёшь денег - то мы расскажем всем.

Comment: @donRumata - познавательно... тянет на микро-рассказ! я просто никогда не сталкивался, потому что если уж Винда, то MSDN-образы - наше всё...

Comment: Ну значит ты никогда не помогал знакомым с компьютером после того как "сын маминой подруги" (тоже мем, если чё) почитав журнах ][акер решил, что щас сам всё сделает, а потом семейный фотоархив за 10 лет куда-то делся.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я знаю, как починить, но не могу объяснить, почему сработало.

Я собрал докер по вашей инструкции, зашел внутрь и посмотрел установленные пакеты:

```
root@d4b3cdbccc0c:/# apt list --installed | grep dotnet

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

dotnet-apphost-pack-6.0/jammy-updates,now 6.0.108-0ubuntu1~22.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
dotnet-host/jammy-updates,now 6.0.108-0ubuntu1~22.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
dotnet-hostfxr-6.0/jammy-updates,now 6.0.108-0ubuntu1~22.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
dotnet-runtime-6.0/jammy-updates,now 6.0.108-0ubuntu1~22.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
dotnet-sdk-6.0/jammy,now 6.0.400-1 amd64 [installed]
dotnet-targeting-pack-6.0/jammy-updates,now 6.0.108-0ubuntu1~22.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

Меня смутил разнобой в версиях между `dotnet-sdk-6.0` и остальными пакетами. SDK версии 6.0.400-1, а остальные пакеты 6.0.108-0ubuntu1~22.04.1

Я откатил SDK на ту же версию, что и остальные пакеты - и вдруг оно заработало:

```
oot@f80d2eecb57f:/# dotnet --version
6.0.108
root@f80d2eecb57f:/# dotnet --list-sdks
6.0.108 [/usr/lib/dotnet/dotnet6-6.0.108/sdk]
```

Укажите в Dockerfile конкретную версию SDK. Это выглядит уродски, но в данный текущий момент времени работает. Потом перестанет работать ))

```
RUN apt-get install -y dotnet-sdk-6.0=6.0.108-0ubuntu1~22.04.1
```

Comment: Какая самая превосходная степень от "великолепно"??!! Огромное спасибо за Ваш эксперимент и за Ваш ответ, для меня-очень поучительно!